# Case-insensitive router.base with nuxt.js and IIS

Tags: iis, vue.js, case-insensitive, nuxt.js

If I generate a site with nuxt, specifying `router.base` in `nuxt.config.js` then host it in an IIS server, all works as expected if the requested URL path starts with the specified `router.base` exactly.

Say, for example router.base = "/Foo/" and the page is named "Bar" then http://example.com/Foo/Bar loads just fine. So does http://example.com/Foo/bar, so it does not appear that page names are case sensitive.

However, if I use a different case for the `router.base` portion of the URL, then the page loads, but it appears that page lifecycle methods (such as `data()`, `created()`, `head()`, etc.) do not run, although the layout `mounted()` method does load. This would happen if I were to use a URL like http://example.com/foo/Bar in the previous example.

So my question is... is there a way to run page lifecycle methods when the case of the URL path differs from the `router.base` value?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really fix the issue, but it seems one can redirect the page early in the loading process to a page with a path that starts with the router.base exactly.  So in `/layouts/default.vue`, I now have:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    let escapeRegExp = function(string) {
      return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
    }
    if (this.$route.fullPath.indexOf(this.$router.options.base) == -1 &&
        this.$route.fullPath.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.$router.options.base.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
      let base = this.$router.options.base
      let regex = new RegExp("(//[^/]+)"+escapeRegExp(base),"i")
      let newLoc = document.location.href.replace(regex,"$1"+base)
      if (newLoc != document.location.href) {
        document.location.replace(newLoc)
      }
    }
  }
}
```